# How to open mac terminal using gtk#

Tags: c#, macos, mono, gtk#

I have made a gtk# tool in Mac OS using xamarin. The problem is that, i want to open Mac terminal and pass some arguments.

From my code i was opening windows console like this but i want to do this for MAC.

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo ();
    info.FileName="cmd.exe";
    info.Arguments ="/C commands||pause";
    p.StartInfo = info;
    p.Start ();
```

Is there any other way of achieving this thing like making a shell file and make changes in it and execute etc. 
This is my first time i am working on Mac. Please explain from scratch. i Can't find related information on internet.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Jaguar (OS X 10.2) then the Terminal app will be in the /Applications/Utilities folder as previously posted. If it is not there, then it has been deleted. In this case, you'll either need to obtain a copy from another Mac system, or repair your OS X installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the terminal with this command.

```
$ open /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app
```

Or just call bash or sh

```
$ bash <options> <file>

$ sh <options> <file>
```

You will see the options in the manual page.

Just type this command into the terminal on your Mac or even Linux.

```
$ man bash
```